# bash printf: How do I output \x and \f within double quotes?

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to printf an input with variables and need double quotes. My output needs a \x and \f text output.

```
printf "\x"
```

or

```
printf "\\x"
```

produces the error:

```
./pegrep.in: line 94: printf: missing hex digit for \x
```

while

```
printf "\f"
```

or

```
printf "\\f"
```

produces nothing at all (in a text output I believe it creates ^L)

single quotes however works for x (but not f). I tried enclosing

```
printf "...'\\x'..."
```

and got the same error as standard double quotes. Have also tried /// to no avail.

Comment: Using double quotes *in the format string itself* is bad practice absent a very compelling reason. In general, the format string should be a constant, and any substitutions should be parameterized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's understand how quoting works.

The simplest form of quoting is the backslash: it prevents the following character from being interpreted in any special way, allowing it to be used as a literal character. For example:

```
# Two arguments to printf
$ printf '%s\n' a b
a
b
# One three-character argument to printf
printf '%s\n' a\ b
a b
```

---

Double quotes are equivalent to escaping every character contained therein: `"a b c"` is equivalent to `\a\ \b\ \c`, which is the same as `a\ b\ c` because `a`, `b`, and `c` have no special meaning to begin with. You can think of every character inside double quotes as being treated literally, with the following exceptions:

1. `$` can start a parameter expansion or a command substitution. Escape it with a backslash to treat it literally.

   ```
    $ foo=3
    $ echo "$foo"
    3
    $ echo "\$foo"
    $foo
   ```
2. A backquote starts a command substitution. Escape it with a backslash to treat it literally.

   ```
   $ echo "`pwd`"
   /home/me
   $ echo "\`pwd\`"
   `pwd`
   ```
3. A double quote ends a quoted string. Escape it with a backslash to treat it literally.

   ```
   $ echo "\""
   "
   ```
4. Because a backslash might be part of one of the three preceding sequences, escape *it* with a backslash to treat one literally.

   ```
   $ echo "\\"
   \
   ```

---

Inside *single* quotes, everything is treated literally, including any use of a backslash. (One consequence of this is that it is impossible to put a single quote in a single-quoted string, because it will always terminate such a string.)

```
$ echo '\'
\
```

---

Once you understand quoting, you next need to realize that `printf` *itself* can process whatever backslashes it sees in its first argument.

```
$ printf 'a\x20b\n'  # a, space (ASCII 0x20), b, newline
a b
```

In order to ensure a string is printed literally no matter *what* characters are present, use the `%s` format specifier and pass your string as a second argument:

```
$ printf '\x41\n'
A
$ printf '%s\n' '\x41'
\x41
```

Comment: very good explanation indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confusing the `\` and the `%` characters.  The `%` is used to output formatted variable contents.  I think this when `\f` is outputs `^L` (aka ASCII FF) that escape sequence is working as documented.

The `printf` argument can be quoted with single quotes.  Then you can use double quotes within it and they will be part of the output:

```
printf '"%x"' 4011  # output:  "fab"
```

Similarly for floating point:

```
print '"%f"' 2.2   # output: "2.200000"
```

The `\` character is for escape sequences of otherwise unprintable characters.

See `man printf` for a full list of the `%` format characters and their meanings.